# How do i disable HttpOnly cookies in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have set the cookie in Vaadin and try to get it from another application which was running on the different server but I was not able to get that cookie what i have set in Vaadin?

We need to disable httpOnly cookie.

***Can anyone help me "How to solve this issue?"***

Answer (score 1):

The cookies set in header `Set-Cookie`. To get it you can use the following code:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("url-of-your-web-app-here").openConnection();
List<String> cookiesList = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
```

You can delete flag manually, by deleting `HttpOnly`:

`response.setHeader( "Set-Cookie", "name=value; HttpOnly");`

If you’re working in a **Servlet 3.0** or newer environment, configure your **web.xml** as following:

```
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
      <http-only>false</http-only>
   </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Note. The `HttpOnly` flag is an additional flag that is used to prevent an **XSS**(Cross-Site Scripting) exploit from gaining access to the session cookie.

See Also:

- [**URLConnection**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)
- [**XSS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
- [**HttpOnly cookie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, Is there any alternative to solve this issue using Java Spec because. I have changed web.xml configuration but which was not working.

Comment: I am able to get the cookie when the server is running in http protocol. Our application server is running in https protocol with secure credentials. So this is also one of the reason to face this kind of issue. Is there any other IDEA to get the cookie and solve this issue without changing the configuration file?